# How to add or subtract within a certain range

Tags: java, python, math, addition, subtraction

I am trying to add numbers but keep it within a range. If it oversteps or understeps the boundary it will circle back to the other boundary.

Examples:

Min: 10
Max: 50

- 20 + 10 = 30
- 20 + 30 = 50 (or 0 idrk)
- 20 + 31 = 1
- 40 + 20 = 10
- 40 + 70 = 10
- 40 - 10 = 30
- 10 - 30 = 30
- 10 - 20 = 40
- 10 - 70 = 40

I am looking for two functions, one to add, one to subtract. I don't really care which language but python or java is preferred. Thanks for any help!

Comment: you'll need to use `abs` and `%` ( modulo ) in python to achieve this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why is 20+31 = 1 ?? Shouldnt it be 19 ?

Comment: This is simply (a + b ) % 50, or (a - b) % 50, where a, b are the numbers in the expressions, and the operations are '+' or '-'.

Comment: I think the question is a little more tricky because of `If it oversteps or understeps the boundary it will circle back to the other boundary.`

I am still not sure how `20+31 = 1` in the above example :/

Comment: If the min of the range is 10, and the max is 50, shouldn't 20 + 31 be 10? Shouldn't 40 + 20 = 50 + 1 + 9 = 19?

Comment: @SerialLazer -- why 19? 20 + 31 = 20 + 30 + 1 = 50 + 1 = 10, since "_If it oversteps or understeps the boundary it will circle back to the other boundary,_" and the other boundary is 10.

Comment: @exnihilo honestly the question is quite vague and ill-formed :)
There could be multiple definitions of circle back to the other boundary.
My assumption was how much ever it goes outside the boundary, it rebounds back :D

Comment: @SerialLazer -- that doesn't make a lot of sense, but neither does the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
# define the range
start = 0
end = 93

#  this function accepts positive and negative numbers in x
def mover(current_place, x):
    locate = current_place + x
    locate = locate % (end-start) # if x > the range
    if locate > end:
        locate = locate - end
    if locate < start:
        locate = locate + end
    return locate


if __name__ == "__main__":
    current_place = 50
    print(current_place) #50
    current_place = mover(current_place, 10)
    print(current_place) #60
    current_place = mover(current_place, -20)
    print(current_place) #40
    current_place = mover(current_place, -50)
    print(current_place) #83
    current_place = mover(current_place, 220)
    print(current_place) #24
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid we have to add more specific information to your question:

- is the boundary inclusive or exclusive?
- are we talking abount only interger numbers or floating numbers?

If you want to use your routine as library function for many purposes, it's maybe a good idea to define one end as inclusive and the other as exclusive.

The following (incomplete) Java program shows the direction of solution as well as the problem with boundaries: whenever the boundary is hit, it flips to other end of your value frame:

```
public class FramedAddSub {

int min;
int max;
int value;

public FramedAddSub(int min, int max, int value) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.value = value;
}

public FramedAddSub add(int toAdd) {
    final int diff = max - min;

    if (toAdd >= 0) {
        // step 1: norm to zero
        value -= min;

        // step 2: rest of division
        value = (value + toAdd) % diff;

        // step 3: re-norm to old offset
        value += min;
    } else {
        // step 1: norm to zero from other end
        value -= max;
        
        // step 2:
        value = (value + toAdd) % diff;
        
        // step 3: re-norm back
        value += max;
    }

    return this;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FramedAddSub test = new FramedAddSub(20, 50, 20);

    System.out.println("start: " + test.value);
    test.add(10);
    System.out.println("+10: " + test.value);
    test.add(20);
    System.out.println("+20: " + test.value);
    test.add(1);
    System.out.println("+1: " + test.value);
    test.add(30);
    System.out.println("+30 should just turn around circle: " + test.value);
    test.add(-1);
    System.out.println("-1: " + test.value);
    test.add(-1);
    System.out.println("-1: " + test.value);
    test.add(-30);
    System.out.println("-30 should just turn around circle: " + test.value);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in python:

```
ans = abs(a + b) % 50
```

You need to pass `a` and `b` as negative numbers, if you want to do a substraction.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I use this solution for integers.

( ( (**X** ± **Y**) - **MaximumValue**  ) % ( **MaximumValue** - **MinimumValue** ) ) + **MinimumValue**

<sub>% : modulo/reminder operator</sub>

**Update:**

The expression above works perfectly on Excel, but according to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mod-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3) it calculates the modulo like this

MOD(n, d) = n - d*INT(n/d)

Combine this two we got

((**X**+**Y**)-**Mx**)-(**Mx**-**Mn**)*Math.floor(((**X**+**Y**)-**Mx**)/(**Mx**-**Mn**))+**Mn**

<sub>Mx: MaximumValue</sub>
<sup>Mn: MinimumValue</sup>